# Stubbing HTTP Requests in Swift

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, alamofire, nocilla

I am using Swift for an iOS app, and using Alamofire to perform HTTP requests.

I want to write unit tests to cover my functions, but I'm having trouble stubbing the HTTP requests performed by Alamofire. I am using Nocilla (imported into bridging header) to try to stub my HTTP requests but it seems that the callback to my HTTP request never gets reached in the tests.

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience successfully stubbing HTTP requests for Alamofire in their test suites?

Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely possible, if you could post some code of what you're setting up, it would be much easier to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't but this is the general pattern that I use for unit testing HTTP requests (calling REST APIs specifically). I've used this successfully for both Alamofire and AFNetworking.

1. I normally have a class that "wraps" (let's call it `Service`) the underlying network APIs (Alamofire, AFNetworking, or just the pure iOS APIs). `Service` typically is stateless and is responsible for making the calls "nicer" for my application.
2. For me, `Service` is typically closely related to the REST API I am trying to consume. For example, if I was using a REST API that allowed me to POST to a `Person` collection, I would have an API like `Service.PostPerson`, `Service.GetPerson`, etc.
3. My application classes (typically the controllers) that use `Service` and typically use `inversion of control` to create `Service`.
4. In my unit tests, I supply a `UnitTestService` so that my classes end up using an instance of `UnitTestService` instead of an instance of `Service`.
5. To make things simple, my `UnitTestService` generally returns hard coded JSON responses based on configuration. So in the example above, I would have a hard coded JSON response for `Service.PostPerson`.

I've used a number of techniques to do this:

- Have a protocol `ServiceProtocol` that both `Service` and `UnitTestService` implement
- Have a single `Service` that is instantiated with a set of closures. These closures do the real work, and you can supply different closures depending on whether you are connecting to the Internet or mocking it.

Because I have some functional programming background, I like the latter. But both techniques work.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't come back to this for a while but your reply was something along the lines of what I was looking for